# ffmpeg-converted video file won't play in Windows Media Player or Movies & TV

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, conversion, h.264, windows

I am using [ffmpeg-python](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/) to convert an hevc mkv file to an h264 mp4. This is the relevant code:

```
ffmpeg.input(video_file).output(out_name, vcodec='libx264', **{'pix_fmt': 'yuv420p'}).run()
```

Yet after converting the file, the resulting mp4 will only play in certain media players. Here is the result of running ffprobe on the mp4:

[image: ffprobe output]

I know this should be possible, so does anyone have an idea of why it isn't playing in older/more standard media players?

Comment: Possibly, the 6 channels in the audio. Add the CLI option `-ac 2` and check.

Comment: @Gyan Wow, this worked! I never would have even thought to try this! If you want to give this as an answer then I'll accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legacy media players like Windows Media Player may be finicky about the files they will accept. In this case, it looks like the audio channel count of 6 is too high.

Add the CLI option `-ac 2` and check.

Comment: To be clear, the "Movies & TV" app, which was added in Windows 10, also was not able to play the video with 6 audio channels. Either way, thanks a lot for the help :)